# Reuse existing Selenium session with Haskell and webdriver

Tags: selenium, haskell, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Trying to use Selenium from Haskell (with `webdriver` package) in a REPL session. To start things I run this:

```
startup :: IO ()
startup = do
  runSession chromeConfig $ do
    openPage "http://www.google.com"
```

New Chrome browser opens, navigates to Google, leaves it there and `startup` function is done and the Chrome browser is still open (that's just like I need it).

Now I'd like to write simple scripts to interact with Google page and run them from the REPL. How can I reuse already existing session / Chrome browser that's open?

If I try with runSession again, it opens a new browser (as the docs say). If I try to use `runWD`, it needs a session as a first parameter, which I don't have yet.

There is a `sessions :: WebDriver wd => wd [(SessionId, Capabilities)]` value, but to use it I have to be inside `runWD` and that needs a session! Furthermore, it returns a `SessionID` and I don't see any function to turn that into a `WDSession`.

I'm going in circles here, any help appreciated. I'm not sure why is this so complicated, is because of Selenium or Haskell?

Answer (score 4):

The `WD` monad is an instance of [`MonadIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#t:MonadIO), which means you can interleave WebDriver actions with IO actions using [`liftIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#v:liftIO). This allows you to read and write to the the console. The idea is to do everything inside a single call to `runSession`.

```
main = runSession chromeConfig $ do
    openPage "http://www.google.com"

    liftIO $ putStrLn "Enter your search term"
    searchTerm <- liftIO getLine

    input <- findElem "#lst-ib"

    sendKeys input searchTerm
    submit input
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm explicitly looking for a solution that does not require writing all fo the code inside one `runSession` block.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of the library before, but poking around now, I see `runSession` appears to indicate it will create a new session given a configuration and run a `WD` action.

So perhaps something like this could work:

```
do
  session <- runSession defaultConfig getSession
  runWD session (return ())
```

`getSession` should work because `WD` is an instance of `WDSessionState`. `runSession` explicitly says that the session is not closed automatically, so hopefully it can be reused.

Comment: I did try something like that, but it doesn't survive a GHCi reload.

Comment: @kmelva You can use "foreign-store" http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foreign-store to make the session persist across GHCi reloads. But perhaps the simplest way is to read the session from a predetermined file path (perhaps having an environment variable pointing to the file, for a bit of flexibility).

Comment: @kmelva Why do you want/need it to persist across a reload? Is this for development convenience, or a fundamental part of the target workflow? Looking at `WDSession` I think the only part that would probably be difficult to serialize is the `Manager`. I'm not familiar with `foreign-store` mentioned by @danidiaz - perhaps that is an easy easy way to get something working.